# android: handler

Tags: android, handler

I am developing a kind of memory game app, where initially the 6 buttons will show some figures. Then when the below MyCount5sec and handler operates, after 5 sec of waiting period for user to remember, the handler will invoke txtClearRun whereby all the texts on every buttons to be erased.

Then after the 5 sec waiting period, it comes the testing period. The user has to select the button in sequence, ie. the latter button value must need to be greater than the earlier button value.

If the user is sucessful (ie. pressed all 6 number buttons), the app should wait 1.5 sec according to postDelay? Yet it appears that there are no delays.

If the user is wrong, ie. pressed button with value smaller than the previous one, the user fails and the app should also wait 1.5sec, with the button highlighted in red. However, it seems that there are no such 1.5sec delay too. No highlighting in red neither.

### Question

1. Why there appears no delays? TWO handlers cannot be invoked at the same time?
2. how could that be further modified?

Thanks a lot!!

```
   private void setQup() 
   {    
          .....

          MyCount5sec counter5sec = new MyCount5sec(6000,1000);
           counter5sec.start(); 
           handler.postDelayed(txtClearRun, 6000);

           pressed = 0;
           temp = 0;
           final int txtClearRun1time = 1500; // set here!
           button_space1.setText("reset press "+pressed);

           Button11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override 
                  public void onClick(View v) {vibrate(); int i=0; Button11.setEnabled(false);
                    if (i == B0) {puttobutton(B0,0);} if (i == B1) {puttobutton(B1,1);} if (i == B2) {puttobutton(B2,2);}
                    if (i == B3) {puttobutton(B3,3);} if (i == B4) {puttobutton(B4,4);} if (i == B5) {puttobutton(B5,5);}
                    pressed = pressed + 1;
                    int buttonvalue = Integer.parseInt(Button11.getText().toString());                    
                    if (pressed >5) 
                    {
                        TotalScores=TotalScores+20;
                        handler1.postDelayed(txtClearRun1, txtClearRun1time);
                        loadNextQup();                      
                    }                   
                    if (buttonvalue < temp) 
                    {
                        Button11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_btn);
                        TotalScores=TotalScores-10;
                        handler1.postDelayed(txtClearRun1, txtClearRun1time);                       
                        loadNextQup();
                    }
                    temp = buttonvalue;
                    }});

    ......same for other buttons..
    }


   Runnable txtClearRun = new Runnable()
   {
       public void run() {blankbutton();} //remove text on buttons
   };

   Runnable txtClearRun1 = new Runnable()
   {
       public void run() {} // solely for wish to delay operations
   };

   private void loadNextQup()
   {

       if (TerminateOrNot ==0) 
       {
           handler.removeCallbacks(txtClearRun);
           handler1.removeCallbacks(txtClearRun1);
           setQup();
       }
         ....
       }
```

Comment: *the app should wait 1.5 sec according to postDelay?* `postDelayed` only delays the code that is in the `Runnable`. Also, did you debug the `loadNextQup` to see if `TerminateOrNot` fulfills that condition(because if it's `0` then the delayed `Runnables` will be delayed.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried make a simple game working on your rules ;) Instead of shapes I used checking background colors and text. I hope you will understand it, maybe this will help you some.

This is full working project:

Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5, bt6, bt7, bt8, bt9, restart;
List<Button> listButtons;
Handler handler1;
List<Integer> buttonColors;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    listButtons.add(bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1));
    listButtons.add(bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2));
    listButtons.add(bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt3));
    listButtons.add(bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt4));
    listButtons.add(bt5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt5));
    listButtons.add(bt6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt6));
    listButtons.add(bt7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt7));
    listButtons.add(bt8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt8));
    listButtons.add(bt9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt9));

    setAllEnabled(false);

    // add on click listeners
    for (int i = 0; i < listButtons.size(); i++) {
        final int index = i;

        //final because i will need it deeper
        final Button s = listButtons.get(i);

        //on click
        s.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //when user click on something then show the origini color and tap "x"
                s.setBackgroundColor(buttonColors.get(index));
                s.setText("x");

                // get all checked
                List<Button> listChecked = countChecked();

                // if checked more == 2
                if (listChecked.size() == 2) {

                    // check if the same text was checked
                    boolean btnsHasTheSameTextAndBackgroundTag = checkAllTextAndBackgroundTag(listChecked);

                    //if they dont have same color and text then reset them
                    if (!btnsHasTheSameTextAndBackgroundTag) {
                        for (Button b : listChecked) {
                            b.setText("");
                            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#565656"));
                        }
                    }
                }

                //finall if user clicked 3 the same colors
                else if (listChecked.size() == 3) {

                    // check if the same text was checked
                    boolean btnsHasTheSameTextAndBackgroundTag = checkAllTextAndBackgroundTag(listChecked);

                    if (btnsHasTheSameTextAndBackgroundTag) {
                        for (Button b : listChecked) {
                            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            b.setText("");
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (Button b : listChecked)
                            {b.setText("");
                            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#565656"));
                            }
                    }
                }

            }

            private boolean checkAllTextAndBackgroundTag(List<Button> list) {
                int number = (Integer) list.get(0).getTag();

                for (Button b : list) {
                    // if one of them will fail
                    if (!b.getText().equals("x") || number != (Integer)b.getTag())
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            private List<Button> countChecked() {
                List<Button> temp = new ArrayList<Button>();

                for (Button b : listButtons) {
                    if (b.getText().equals("x"))
                        temp.add(b);
                }
                return temp;
            }
        });
    }

    restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_restart);

    // we go on.. create list of colors
    final List<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    colorList.add(Color.parseColor("#C3C3E5"));
    colorList.add(Color.parseColor("#F1F0FF"));
    colorList.add(Color.parseColor("#8C489F"));

    // on restart button action
    restart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //enable all
            setAllEnabled(true);

            // remember new colors and create for it container
            buttonColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // create random
            Random r = new Random();

            // get temp counter used colors
            int[] wastedColor = new int[colorList.size()];

            // for all buttons do the same job
            for (int i = 0; i < listButtons.size(); i++) {

                Log.d("xxx", i + "");

                // take first random number
                int numberRandom = r.nextInt(colorList.size());

                // check if we have all colors with the same amount
                while (wastedColor[numberRandom] == colorList.size())
                    numberRandom = r.nextInt(colorList.size());

                // increment existing ones
                wastedColor[numberRandom]++;

                // remmeber this color
                buttonColors.add(colorList.get(numberRandom));

                listButtons.get(i).setTag(numberRandom);
                listButtons.get(i).setBackgroundColor((int) (colorList.get(numberRandom)));
                listButtons.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            // after generated colors...

            handler1 = new Handler();

            // hide after 5 sec
            handler1.postDelayed(new HideAllColors(), 5000);

        }
    });

}

private void setAllEnabled(boolean status) {
    for(Button b : listButtons)
        b.setEnabled(status);

}

private class HideAllColors implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Button b : listButtons)
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#565656"));

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt1"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt2"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt4"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt5"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt4"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt7"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#565656" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bt6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt8"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#565656" />


    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt_restart"
        android:text="restart"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#565656" />






</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response...I am out of town...many many thanks for your help! Your advice is great!